# Get info about a post request in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, post, httpwebrequest, forms, form-post, http-post

need to identify the url that have made a post request to a web site page.
How can i get the sender url (the url that have made the post request) ?

Is this information reliable? or it can be manipulated?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

Request.UrlReferrer

will give you the referrer if present.

Comment: Can requesst.UrlReferrer by haked? is request.urlreferrer always present in a post request?

Comment: It is just a http header. The client could write anything in that header variable.

Comment: so what can i do to be sure that a post request came from a trusted domain?

Comment: you can only assure this if you have some kind of authentication. i. e. you could use the windows authentiction

Comment: So what i have to do: suppose i'm expecting a post request from www.icanposttoyou.com, i can't use urlreferrer because someone can change the header, i can't install any certificate because the caller is a third party, i can share a secret param between the two system, what else

Comment: There is nothing what can really secure you based on referrer or client ip address. You should think about implementing some kind of secure handshaking (authentication) with your client.